# Printing invoice fromAndroid Tablet

Tags: android, printing, tablet, android-4.4-kitkat, invoice

How to connect the thermal printer to Android tablet for getting print my invoice.

if any one know please give me a procedure and code samples for taking print from Tablet..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In market no of thermal printer are available like EPSON, Casio, STAR or Chinese printers. These printers have their own SDK. By simply import that sdk in project you can print from the application.